# WinUi 3 MVVM C# Application needs background file sync - How to do that? BackgroundTasks?

Tags: c#, service, synchronization, winui-3, background-task

I have written a WinUi 3 MVVM application in C# to synchronize future files from my web project hosted on Firebase at the users in a c:\*\Docs\myApp\files.

It is already connected to the database and now I need a method to have the files synchronized on a regular basis.

I found something about Background Tasks, tried to implement this but failed. I saw too late that this was for a UWP project.

#### Basic question, are BackgroundTasks what I need? Are there other approaches? A Windows Service Project mabye?

If Background Tasks are what I need, here are my files:

##### Package.appxmanifest

```
<Package [...]>
    <Applications>
        <Application Id="App"
          Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
          EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
            [...]
            <Extensions>
                [...]
                <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BackgroundTasks.BackgroundTask">
                    <BackgroundTasks>
                        <Task Type="timer" />
                    </BackgroundTasks>
                </Extension>
            </Extensions>
        </Application>
    </Applications>
    <Extensions>
        <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
            <InProcessServer>
                <Path>PitBoard ACC Livery Manager.dll</Path>
                <ActivatableClass ActivatableClassId="BackgroundTasks.BackgroundTask" ThreadingModel="both" />
            </InProcessServer>
        </Extension>
    </Extensions>
    [...]
</Package>
```

##### App.xaml.cs

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.
        CreateDefaultBuilder().
        UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory).
        ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            [...]
            services.AddSingleton<BackgroundTaskService>();
        }).
        Build();

        UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
    }


    protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        base.OnLaunched(args);

        await App.GetService<BackgroundTaskService>().RegisterBackgroundTasksAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    }
```

##### BackgroundTaskService

```
    public async Task RegisterBackgroundTasksAsync()
    {
        BackgroundExecutionManager.RemoveAccess();
        var result = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

        if (result == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedBySystemPolicy
            || result == BackgroundAccessStatus.DeniedByUser)
        {
            return;
        }

        foreach (var task in BackgroundTasks)
        {
            task.Register();
        }
    }
```

##### SyncBackgroundTask

```
    public override void Register()
    {
        var taskName = GetType().Name;
        var taskRegistration = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Value.Name == taskName).Value;

        if (taskRegistration == null)
        {
            var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder()
            {
                Name = taskName
            };

            // details at https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-an-inproc-background-task
            builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(30, false));

            // TODO: Find someone who can get this Background Task running
            builder.Register();
        }
    }
```

`builder.Register();` throws an unhandled exception 'Value does not fall within expected range'

[image]

Comment: I can reproduce same issue, and I will discuss with the team if In-Progress supports WinUI3. For service, you can refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/using-services

Comment: Refer to Andrew Leader-MSFT's answer in [this thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/680911/(winui-3)-in-process-background-task) . You need to use [the COM background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-winmain-background-task) in WinUI3.

Answer (score 0):

Edit project and change this key to:

```
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.15063.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

I think this is a bug that newer builds throw that error.